# Transistor types

Tags: transistors

I've just been looking at data sheets to find the current gain of some transistors I've bought, but it has different values for "type 16, 25, 40". How do I know what type the ones I have are and what does the type refer to?

Comment: how can we see the datasheet? and what is printed on part?

Comment: http://www.redrok.com/PNP_BC327_-45V_-800mA_0.625W_Hfe100_TO-92.pdf

Comment: That one shows what I'm talking about clearly, but they all do something similar when discussing Hfe

Comment: The part should have it embossed on. If not then your supplier should have made it clear which you were buying. The 'type' refers to the gain the transistor has.

Comment: These aren't "types" they are "hfe classifications" according to the  datasheet - it's just gain binning like the old BC107a,b,c instead of un-binned BC107. Datasheet doesn't say how they are marked. Mayeb the full databook covers it in another section, but I'd expect it to be printed on the package.

Answer (score 0):

This classification for hFE binning appears to be a number that is 10% of the mean bin value.   If not specified on order then you get “open bin” which means any bin.  Fortunately inexpensive DMM’s have hFE testing.  Refer to datasheet for marking codes.